# line contains NUL error in reading a .dat file

Tags: python, null, ascii, dat-protocol

I want to read a dat file in python but I received the NUL error :

```
`from astropy.io import ascii`
ascii.read('fx=0.1_RHS=0.5_fa=0.5_x_lightcone_dtb_6minres.dat')

Error: line contains NUL
```

how can I solve this issue?

I've tried to read this file with csv.reader() through the following code. finally I could open the file but I suppose it's not an appropriate choice:

```
import csv

with open('fx=0.1_RHS=0.5_fa=0.5_x_lightcone_dtb_6minres.dat', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    while True:
        try:
            row = next(reader)
            print(row)
        except csv.Error:
            continue
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

these are some lines of the result which looks wrong:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goJE6.png)

Comment: If it contains NUL, it's a binary file, not a text file.

Comment: thank you for your response. should I open this file with another library?

Comment: @Barmar: technically it could also be UTF-16

Comment: @SaraGholamhoseinian: we don't know the structure of that file and `.dat` is a very generic file extension that doesn't necessarily imply any specific format, so you'll have to check with the source of the files to see how they are supposed to be interacted with.